# To show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}$ $\frac{n^{2}}{2^{n}} = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

We need to show that that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}$ $\frac{n^{2}}{2^{n}} = 0$.
This makes sense intuitively since exponentials always rush to infinity faster than do polynomials, but I don't know how to prove it.

Cool thing is, this is actually not from a math class, but from my CS class, where we have to compare runtimes. Regardless, can someone show me how to prove this without using differentiation? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Can you show that $0 \le \frac{n^2}{2^n} \le \frac{1}{n}$ for $n \ge 10$?

Comment: @user00000000001899 Try induction or check the great answers on the duplicate question.